# Simple GAN predicts NaN in Tensorflow after 2 steps

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm implementing a basic GAN based on the one in the [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan).

After 2 training steps, the prediction from the generator is all NaN.

I don't know why it happens, but I noticed that the gradients of the 2nd convolution layer of the discriminator are all NaN since the first step:

> <tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 5, 64, 128), dtype=float32, numpy=
> array([[[[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan], [nan, nan, nan,

My loss functions:

```
loss = BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

def generator_loss(discriminator_output):
    loss_value = loss(tf.ones_like(discriminator_output), discriminator_output)
    print(f"Generator loss: {loss_value}")
    return loss_value

def discriminator_loss(outputs_for_reals, outputs_for_fakes):
    real_loss = loss(tf.ones_like(outputs_for_reals), outputs_for_reals)
    fake_loss = loss(tf.zeros_like(outputs_for_fakes), outputs_for_fakes)
    print(f"Disc loss (real/fake): {real_loss}/{fake_loss}")

    return real_loss + fake_loss
```

The training loop:

```
def training_step(self, real_images):
    noise = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, NOISE_DIM])

    with tf.GradientTape() as generator_tape, tf.GradientTape() as discriminator_tape:
        generated_images = self._generator(noise, training=True)
        if True in tf.math.is_nan(generated_images)[0, 0, :, 0]:
            print("NaN result found")
        else:
            print("OK Result")

        results_for_real = self._discriminator(real_images, training=True)
        results_for_fake = self._discriminator(generated_images, training=True)

        generator_loss = self._generator_loss(results_for_fake)
        discriminator_loss = self._discriminator_loss(results_for_real, results_for_fake)

    generator_gradients = generator_tape.gradient(generator_loss,
                                                  self._generator.trainable_variables)
    discriminator_gradients = discriminator_tape.gradient(discriminator_loss,
                                                          self._discriminator.trainable_variables)


    self._generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(
        zip(generator_gradients, self._generator.trainable_variables))
    self._discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(
        zip(discriminator_gradients, self._discriminator.trainable_variables))

    return generator_loss, discriminator_loss, generated_images
```

I build the models exactly the same way as in the documentation.

Things I tried:

- Reducing the learning rate
- Running the model in different `training` modes (`training=False`/`training=True`)
- Decorating the training step with `tf.function`

No matter what I do, calling the generator with any input will produce exclusively `NaN` elements.
Example output:

```
2020-12-11 18:15:42.783543: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:314] Internal: Invoking GPU asm compilation is supported on Cuda non-Windows platforms only
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. 
Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.
This message will be only logged once.
OK Result
Generator loss: 1.5484254360198975
Disc loss (real/fake): 1.4994642734527588/0.2869953215122223
OK Result
Generator loss: 1.2899521589279175
Disc loss (real/fake): 1.3189733028411865/0.3767632842063904
Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
NaN result found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used RTX3080 which only works with CUDA 11, and I was using CUDA 10.1. With 10.1 it works without warnings but produces garbage/nan values